# Swift segue transition shadow

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I'm working with a few standard segues in storyboard and they each have the same background color. The issue I'm having is that when the segue transition nears completion there appears a dark shadow like background around the whole frame.

[image: Image showing transition]

It's very faint, but enough to cause an issue. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Yes. It's when the leaving view controller is animating away. Using push and present. Not when presenting a controller modally from the bottom.

Comment: From a view perspective it's as if the segue is adding a shadow overlay on top of the leaving view controller for aesthetics. Not sure how to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, the standard push/pop appears to darken the view that you're pushing from and the one you're popping to. If you don't like that, you'll probably have to define your own custom navigation controller animation.

Comment: Could I perform a custom segue or will that have the darken too?

Comment: Yes, but the standard technique for customizing the animations nowadays is custom transitions, not custom segues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard navigation controller push/pop animations darken the view that you're pushing from and the one you're popping to. If you don't like that, you can customize the transition, using an animation that just slides views in and out, but does no dimming of anything:

```
// this is the view controller you are pushing from

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

}

// make the view controller conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return PushPopAnimator(operation: operation)
    }
}

// The animation controller

class PushPopAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    let operation: UINavigationControllerOperation

    init(operation: UINavigationControllerOperation) {
        self.operation = operation
        super.init()
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let from = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
        let to   = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!

        let rightTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: transitionContext.containerView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
        if operation == .push {
            to.view.transform = rightTransform
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(to.view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: { 
                to.view.transform = .identity
            }, completion: { finished in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            })
        } else if operation == .pop {
            to.view.transform = .identity
            transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(to.view, belowSubview: from.view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
                from.view.transform = rightTransform
            }, completion: { finished in
                from.view.transform = .identity
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

For information on custom transitions with view controllers, see WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/).

Comment: Thanks, have changed the animation in your answer to the default segue for anyone who needs it. The segue isn't taking to account a navigation bar I have in place and moving the views up 64pts. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yep, you can change the `animate(withDuration: ...)` parameters to whatever you want. Having said that, I rejected your edit because you blew away the whole `PushPopAnimator` class definition in the process, which would make this answer pretty hard to understand for people unfamiliar with custom transitions. It's hard enough as it is... ;)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.